# need an sql query

Tags: sql, mysql

I currently have two tables:
1. car(plate_number, brand, cid)
2. borrow(StartDate, endDate, brand, id)

I want to write a query to get all available brand and count of available cars for each brand

Comment: Sounds like a good homework question.  Does your instructor know you're cheating?

Comment: Specify "Available":  for a given date ?

Comment: You may want to consider naming your table with a noun like "loan" instead of the verb "borrow". Tables normally represent entities (things).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.Brand COUNT(plate_number) FROM car as c LEFT JOIN (borrow as b) on c.cid = b.id WHERE endDate < NOW() GROUP BY c.Brand
```

I did not try it but it should work.

Edit: fixed where.

Answer (score 0):

halfpseudo count rows or use sql count or group by, left join also applicable where nullvalues

```
brand from car join borrow on borrow.brand=car.brand where endDate<currentdate
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tables :**

`car(plate_number, brand, cid)`

`borrow(StartDate, endDate, brand, id)`

```
select c.plate_number, b.brand, count(b.brand) as available_number
from   car c, borrow b 
where  c.brand=b.brand
       and end_date>=sysdate 
having count(1)>0
group by c.plate_number, b.brand
```